# Weird web browsers behaviors while setting session variable in Grails

Tags: google-chrome, grails, internet-explorer-11, session-variables

i'm developing application using `Grails 2.5.1` i have a weird behaviors in the web browsers **( Chrome  59.0.3071.115  and Internet explorer 11 )** , what i'm doing is setting a `session` variable in the GSP and checking it in the controller.

In the GSP i'm setting the session variable `isHR` to `true` if the user clicked `id=HR` link

Here is my GSP:

```
<body>
   <script>

$("#HR").on('click', function() {
    alert ("hiii")
    $(document).html("<g:set value="true" var="isHR" scope="session"/>");
});

</script>

<li ><g:link  controller="login" action="auth" elementId='login'>
                        <g:message code='spring.security.ui.login.login' />
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
                    </g:link></li>
<li>

<g:link  elementId='HR'  controller="login" action="auth"  > 

                        <g:message code='employmentSeeker.login.link' />
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>

                        </g:link></li>


</body>
```

here is the controller where i check on the `isHR` session variable :

```
 def create() {
    log.info ("Creating new User")
    println "checking session " +session.isHR
    respond new Users(params)
}
```

the output while using `Chrome` after pressing link with **`id=login`**  or **`id=HR`** :

```
checking session null
```

the output while using `Internet explorer` after pressing link with **`id=login`**  :

```
 checking session true
```

How come this could happen !!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work that way. If you want to set some session-scoped variable from a GSP, you have to call a controller action either per normal request or AJAX, where the variable will be set. Thus it will also be browser-agnostic.

Comment: so why in grails there is something like `<g:set value="true" var="isHR" scope="session"/>`

Comment: the `<set/>` is invoked upon the page rendering rather than on click. so, in order to set it on click you have to do it the way I mentioned